# Compute Engine - CPU Utilization & Load average spikes at mid-night during day switch over

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-20.04

CPU Utilization & Load average on Virtual Instance (Compute Engine) spikes during midnight when day switches. We use 8/6 Core VM instance running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Further, during midnight we don't have much traffic. Regularly, since last 8 months CPU Utilization & Load Average shoots to 100% & 150+ respectively which takes the website down for 1 or 2 minutes till the another VM shoots up to handle the spike. Spike in CPU Utilization/Load Average gets over within 5 minutes. During CPU load spike, spike in Disk throughput & Disk IOPS is also visible but that looks manageable by VM.
It is pretty annoying to receive Website Down/High Traffic alerts (via SMS and Emails) during midnight regularly. I have checked and made sure that -

- It is not log rotation on Ubuntu during midnight as VM console confirms that Log Rotation gets completed before spike occurs.
- MySQL is also responsive and queries per seconds VM sends to MySQL Cloud server remains normal.
- No Google services through API is accessed during midnight by us e.g. Translation API which might take long to finish.

I doubt it might be some house keeping done by Cloud Team on day switch over which might be causing high Load Average. Console Graph for VM shows spike in New connection under Google Services which changes average 70/s to 200/s. I have attached VM observability snapshot.

Looking for some help to resolve the issue.

[image: VM Observability Snapshot]

Comment: The item that stands out is `New connections` of 213 per second. You have a scheduled process on your instance that creates those connections. Your task is to figure out what that process is. Check your cron entries, log files (system and Cloud Logging), etc. A network trace can help pinpoint which Google APIs are being called.

Comment: Additional DB info request - 3 sets from 23:59, 00:01 and 00:05, please. 
Google instance type?
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [John hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) for giving lead! Calling GA4 API was causing spike in CPU Utilization & Load average. GA4 API is not part of Google Cloud and doesn't provide any mean to check the usage so it got skipped while checking for mysterious calls to Google Services API.

We register/log Events in Analytics 4 through GA4 API and during day switch over we have high volume of them. Although, high volume of events don't cause any stress on VM but calling GA4 API was exhausting all resources of VM. We disabled calling GA4 API and issue got fixed. VM observability snapshot after call to GA4 API is removed is attached below.

[image: VM Instance observability snapshot after call to GA4 API is removed]

Comment: GREAT. For performance improving suggestions, provide one set of data from your Google instance after 24 hours of uptime, please.